# Automatically Loop Through Slicer PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a PowerBI dashboard, where I have several visuals all based on names. There are about 14 names. I need to move through the names, exporting to a PDF for each person. Is there a way to automatically loop through the slicer, exporting the dashboard to a PDF for each person? A macro perhaps?

Cheers!

I've tried the PlayAxis custom visual, which has not solved the problem as it doesn't automatically export to a PDF.